# Magento2 php7 memory limit

Tags: php, magento, memory-limit

I have the strange problem. I installed Magento 2 on C9. I installed PHP 7, with all necessary extensions (curl, mbstring, mcrypt and etc). I set the php memory_limit 4096M.
Checked by phpinfo you can see screenshot.
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/905628/sxvelb6o5xrt3q0tilem

But when I try to enable any extension I receive this error.

`Your current PHP memory limit is 64M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more.`

Magento ver. 2.1.6

PHP Ver. 7.0.18-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have it set differently in your virtualhost or on .htaccess.

Comment: HI. No I set the 4096M in htaccess and in php.ini.
You can see the phpinfo here
https://predico-magento-c9-dcg.c9users.io/
thanks

Comment: can you provide the content of the .htaccess at the base of your magento2 directory ?

Comment: You can see the content here https://predico-magento-c9-dcg.c9users.io/htaccess.txt . Thanks

Comment: and the one in pub ? did you allowed override ? I insist because I am almost sure that it comes with .htaccess or virtualhost.

Comment: https://predico-magento-c9-dcg.c9users.io/htaccess_pub.txt.  I see here set the 768M, but not 64M.

Comment: what about AllowOverride ?

Comment: Where I should to add the AllowOverride?

Comment: In virtualhost. To test if it is on, try to make a mistake in your .htaccess. You should have an error

Comment: The root .htaccess file give error, when the htaccess in pub folder is not give any error

Comment: That's most probably normal during installation process with html. Are you running command line installation ?

Comment: No I used the magento2 interface for the install

Comment: Hi. I tried to enable module by command line. 
`$ php bin/magento module:enable Magento_BundleSampleData`    
`$php bin/magento setup:upgrade    `
`$php bin/magento cache:clean`   But nothing happens. just the site becomes slower

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot help you further.